# PHP File Upload Submit not moving Image

Tags: php, html

**Hello Stackers,**

I'm having trouble with a PHP File Upload Script. I Can pick an Image, and click on the Upload button, however it does not even upload the image to the map i Said it should go to, in fact, I can't even find the images at all.

The Folder is in my IIS wwwroot. The path is `wwwroot/magieweb/images/uploader`

What am I doing wrong?

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors="<font color='#e74c3c'>Dit bestand kan niet geupload worden. (Fout EXT)</font>";
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"wwwroot/magieweb/images/uploader/".$file_name);
         $errors = "<font color='#16a085'>Het is gelukt. Het adres is <strong>magiehotel.nl/magieweb/images/uploader/".$_FILES['image']['name']."</strong></font><br><br>";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
```

**The HTML Form**

```
  <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                  <b>Type/pad</b><br>
                  <select name="path">
                  <option value="magieweb/images/publicroom">Publieke Kamer</option>
                  <option value="magieweb/images/news">Nieuwsafbeelding</option>
                  <option value="app/tpl/skins/Habbo/swf/c_images/album1584">Badges</option>
                  </select><div style="margin-bottom:5px;"></div>
                  <b>Afbeelding</b><input type = "file" name = "image" /> <br>




         <input type = "submit"/> of <a href="ase-dash.php">Annuleren</a>
         <br><br>
                <ul style="border: 1px solid #2087A1; list-style-type: none; margin-right:40px;">
            <li><strong style="color:#2087A1; margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:3px;">Uploadbestandinformatie</strong></li> 

            <li><strong>Bestandnaam:</strong> <?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];  ?>
            <li><strong>Bestandgrootte:</strong> <?php echo $_FILES['image']['size'];  ?>
            <li><strong>Bestandtype:</strong> <?php echo $_FILES['image']['type'] ?>
         </ul>

               </form>
```

I Do get the Success Notification, and I do get the Image data, but I can't find the image anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with `/wwwroot/magieweb...` add `/` before `wwwroot`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Have you got any error??

Comment: I've tried to check the succession with `print_r($_FILES)` and it returned `Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => avatarimage.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php7149.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 209 ) )`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using windows system and the path you have given is totally wrong.

If you are using windows system, change the absolute folder path and try.

So the path will be like below

> C:/xampp/your_project/upload_folder/

Also make sure that the folder has write permission to upload the files.

Comment: I Did change the path to `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/magieweb/images/uploader`, and SYSTEM has Writing permission. However, I can't seem to remove the readonly attribute. Is that needed?